# Other methods besides submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP submit form, within that form I have a PHP image gallery that displays images from a folder. (I have a dropdown to select images from different folders).

When I click on an image from the gallery the path to that image is entered into an input field so it can be linked to the other information when submitted.

My problem is when I choose a different image gallery folder from the dropdown it submits the form. I understand why it does this, but am unsure how to change the way it uses PHP to choose different folders to JS/JQ so there is no need for a submit or refresh.

Here is the relevant  code...

```
<script>
function change(){
    document.getElementById("myfolders").submit();
}
</script>


$subF = $_POST['otherFolders'];

<form id="myfolders" method="post">

  <select name="otherFolders" onchange="change()">
        <option selected="selected">Other Galleries</option>
        <?php
        $otherFolders = $dirs2;
        foreach($otherFolders as $item){
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $item; ?>"><?php echo $item; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Sorry but it's unclear what you're asking...

Comment: I see no jquery here. And its a bit unclear what exactly you wish it to do vs what its doing (because obviously it submits on change).

Comment: If you don't need to submit the form, just use jquery to prevent submission. `event.preventDefault();` for example - but you will need to set your script up to use jQuery...

Comment: You could load galleries asynchronously using AJAX. See [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). I suggest giving it a try; then let us know what you tried, where you got stuck, and what specifically went wrong.

Comment: BTW `event.preventDefault();` is not jquery, thats just [standard JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault). So jquery is not needed to prevent the default action in this manner. However jquery is great for doing an ajax call for more data to swap out elements on your DOM.

Comment: "I see no jquery here. And its a bit unclear what exactly you wish it to do vs what its doing (because obviously it submits on change)" Yes that is my question how do I get away from that.I've tried several attempts with ajax but will keep trying Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you dont want to refresh the page when a user clicks on submit. There is very limited info from the question, so I cannot provide changes to your code. But, what you want to do is either prevent the form from submitting by using the `preventDefault();` function in JS and then reading the form elements, submitting an aJax request to your server (PHP), and using the server response to display on the page.

If you do not want the form to even submit, you can just make a button that does not submit a form, but simply has an onClick event that reads the form elements and does the same as above.

Form submit will always refresh the page if not prevented. If an action attribute is not provided, it will default to submitting the form to the current page.

Comment: No, I'm wanting to change what folder the images are coming from the dropdown/select without submitting the form or refreshing the page. But as the code reads "onchange" it submits. Was looking for another alternative.

Comment: Then that would be server side... you only showed a little bit of the code. Nothing about which folder @mark2326